# Formal definition of expectation question

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

I have expectation of a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ defined as: If X is lebesgue integrable with respect to $P$ then $EX = \int_\Omega X \ dP$. What I don't understand is what the author means by "lebesgue integrable with respect to $P$". To my understanding, $X$ being lebesgue integrable means that the integral of $X$ with respect to the lebesgue measure exists, but I don't know what Lebesgue integrable with respect to $P$ means. Does it mean it is both lebesgue integrable and integrable with respect to the measure $P$?

Could someone offer some intuition on this please

Comment: I would say integrable with respect to $P$.  What text is this from?

Comment: It's not from a particular text just from my lectures - but on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value they define it with respect to the lebesgue measure too.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure and the Lebesgue integral are two separate things.  Lebesgue integration is defined with respect to an arbitrary measure. The Lebesgue measure is just one particular (but very prevalent) measure.

Comment: of course, thanks.